# Google adsense account not approved

Tags: adsense

I have created a Web Portal [bugnull.com](http://bugnull.com) and applied for the Adsense account, but my Adsense account is not approved as I received the email that my site is not meeting the Google guidelines.Please review my site and tell me what is wrong in my site and what kind of improvement I should made so that I can have approved Adsense account.

Please tell me as I am really disheartened with this rejection from Google .

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have the Privacy Policy on your site. You could generate one at http://www.serprank.com/privacy-policy-generator/

You should also post your question to the offical Adsense forum: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense